# Difference between two ways to grep from input file

Tags: bash, grep

I have an input file we'll call scan.data. It contains a list of words that I'm going to grep. I've found two different ways of doing this, but I get drastically different results:

```
IFS=$' '    
find / -type f -exec grep -a -D skip -wo $(<scan.data) '{}' \;
```

This nets me 3,799 matches.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -a -D skip -of scan.data '{}' \;
```

This nets me 18,167 matches.

As far as I understand, setting the IFS allows me to output the contents of the subshell as a list, essentially mirroring what the second case does. So what is the difference between these two that causes such a major difference in matches?

Comment: your two grep commands aren't similar -- the first is using the `-w` flag, which will cause it to wrap the pattern(s) in `\<...\>`. Also, settings `IFS` isn't enough -- you'll have to also guard against globs with `set -f`.

Comment: Using `grep ... -o "$(<scan.data)"` (with quotes!) in the 1st command should be no different from the 2nd, though an absolutely pointless and uportable compliction.

Comment: @mosvy can you give me some more information? I understand that the commands are different, I don't understand why they are leading to drastically different results. Also, why would I need to worry about globs when using a -w flag, but not an -f flag reading contents of a file?

Comment: Not only about globs, if your patterns contain `{}`, they will be interpreted by find ;-)

Comment: Try `echo 'foobar' | grep -ow foo` with and without `-w`.

Comment: @mosvy so what you're saying is that the first case is more precise because it strictly matches each pattern because of the wrap from the -w flag, while in the second case, when reading a list from a file, it may also count additional characters before and after the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your command substitution is quoted (if it wasn't, most of the words in `scan.data` would be taken as filenames to run `grep` on) and that the first word in the file does not start with a dash (if it did, it may be interpreted as an option), the two `grep` invocations are mostly equivalent, except for the options used. The first variation may additionally provoke an "argument list too long" error if `scan.data` contains much data.

1. The first `grep` uses `-w`.  This would use the patterns read from `scan.data` as regular expressions and would try to match *complete words*  on each line in the files that `find` provides to the utility (`the` would *not* match at the start of `theodore`).
2. The second `grep` does not use `-w`.  This would use the patterns read from `scan.data` as regular expressions and would try to match *substrings* on each line in the files that `find` provides to the utility (`the` would match at the start of `theodore`).

This may explain the difference in number of matches that you get.

You may possibly want to use `-F` with `grep` as well, if you don't want the utility to use the patterns in your `scan.data` file as regular expressions but as strings (this would be preferable if your pattern file contains characters that are special in regular expressions but that you need to match literally, like `.`, `[`, `*`, etc.).

If you have patterns in a file, consider using `-f` to read them. Using a command substitution is possible but only in a limited number of cases (no initial dash in first string, and only a moderate amount of strings, as mentioned at the top of this answer already).  The existence of the `-f` option makes the use of a command substitution completely unnecessary.

Comment: I understand that using the -w flag in the first example would match complete words. But I notice that the -o flag in the second example also appears to limit the output to exact matches.

Comment: @YK The `-o` option is used in _both_ examples. That option does not influence matching. It affects the result of the match. Without `-o`, the whole matching line is returned. With `-o`, only the match itself is returned (e.g. `the` in `theodore` if `-w` was not used).